# Angular 8 - Error while adding '@nguniversal/express-engine' to project: 'Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {}'

Tags: angular-universal

When I try to install angular universal using the following command
"ng add @nguniversal/express-engine"

I receive the error at the end of the install:

Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {}

Errors:

Data path "" should have required property 'clientProject'.

Any fix for this error? 8.2.12

Comment: Show your `angular.json` file